# Find the k-th largest element in the list

Tags: python

Given a list, find the k-th largest element in the list.

> Input: list = [3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8], k = 3
>
> Output: 5

```
def findKthLargest(nums, k):
    pass

print(findKthLargest([3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 8], 3))
# 5
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) algorithm which has O(n) average time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this. First we would be sorting the array. So all we'd have to do is return the k-last index.

```
def findKthLargest1(nums, k):

    nums.sort()
    return nums[-k]
```

but there is a more interesting way to solve this problem, we can use Heaps. In general, when you hear about "smallest" or "largest". You should think: I need Heaps.

```
import heapq

def findKthLargest2(nums, k):

    minHeap = []
    heapq.heapify(minHeap)

    for x in nums:
        heapq.heappush(minHeap, x)
        if len(minHeap) > k:
            heapq.heappop(minHeap)

    return heapq.heappop(minHeap);
```

Comment: `return heapq.nlargest(k, nums)[-1]`is probably the simplest.

Comment: None of the two has time complexity < O(n log n), do they?

Comment: @Ignatius This is old - but, yes, none of the two has the same time complexity - in fact the complexity should be lower (O(klogn)). In practice, it's not clear whether it would be faster as the list sort in python is highly optimised. It also uses the timsort algorithm which has in practice lower conplexity than O(n*logn).

Answer (score 1):

you can also use:

```
sorted(my_list)[-k]
```

Comment: yes but, my_list.sort() and sorted(my_list) are O(n log n).

Comment: you didn't ask for best in terms of time complexity, but still, if your list is not more than 10k numbers you will not see so much difference

Answer (score 0):

sorted function sorts items in ascending order by default. You call also define reverse parameter (set True for descending order) and get the kth largest:

```
sorted(nums, reverse=True)[k-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

> try to do in time complexity < (n log n)

All solutions provided have n log n complexity.

The following code

```
def findKthLargest(nums, k):
    for _ in range(k):
        s = max(nums)
        t.remove(s)
    return s
```

will require 2(kn - k(k - 1)/2) operations, so its complexity is O(kn).
If k is a constant (not a function of n), complexity is linear O(n).
If k is a function of n but k <  log n for all k, n, complexity is still < n log n.
And if k = O(n) then complexity is O(n^2) which is > n log n and sorting will work faster.

Answer (score -2):

`k = int(input())
l = [6,2,1,9,5]
l.sort()
print(l[-k])`